# RTF Tags removal by regex crashes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, rtf

I am using C++ VS 2008 to strip RTF tags to make a search in the RTF text only.

The RTF text I get from `CRichTextEdit` into `CString` works just fine.
Here how I try to remove the tags:

```
std::tr1::cmatch res;
std::string str = note;
const std::tr1::regex rx("({\\)(.+?)(})|(\\)(.+?)(\b)");
std::string replacement = "";
std::string result = std::tr1::regex_replace(str,rx,replacement);

CString strSearchText = result.c_str();
```

The line 3 crashes on the pattern above.  A simple pattern for a text replacement works just fine: Ex replace `"fast"` from `"fast fox"` with an emplty string.  the crash message is here:

> First-chance exception at 0x7622fbae in ICView.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::tr1::regex_error at memory location 0x0012ee20..
>      First-chance exception at 0x7622fbae in ICView.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
>      Unhandled exception at 0x7622fbae in ICView.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::tr1::regex_error at memory location 0x0012ee20..

Comment: The difficulty (if not impossibility) of parsing markup languages with regular expressions has received a lot of attention on Stack Overflow recently. I'm not familiar enough with RTF to say that the same problems apply, but it seems likely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your backslashes, since they serve as an escape character both in regex and in C++ string literals. This means that to match a single backslash, you need four backslash characters. I think this should work: `"({\\\\)(.+?)(})|(\\\\)(.+?)(\\b)"`

This should fix the exception, but if it still happens you can catch it and use the exception object's what() or code() methods to see what the problem is.

Edit: the braces should also be escaped since they are special characters in regex. so use:

```
"(\\{\\\\)(.+?)(\\})|(\\\\)(.+?)(\\b)"
```

Comment: You are absolutely right pointing out to the backslashes as escape chars - thanks I will change them.
But the problem is not in not properly replacing my strings with new patterns but rather crashing on the line 3 where I declare rx pattern.  The std::tr1::regex_error is thrown as poiniting to wrong memory loccation or so.  If I declare const std::tr1::regex rx("brown fox"); it will work like a charm.  What would be wrong?

Comment: The backslashes are what's wrong. They cause the parantheses to be escaped, which causes an unmatched parantheses error.

Comment: Guys, thanks a million.  Of cause it was the braces that must have been escaped in regex!!!! I stupidly forgot about those #$#$#$#@@
Cheers and happy coding,
Val :-)

Answer (score -1):

Use exception handling if you do not have a control over pattern coming in.

```
std::tr1::regex pattern;
bool bError = false;
try
{
    pattern.assign("*som.thing");
}
catch (std::regex_error error)
{
    bError = true;
}
```